# How to calculate the total of subtotal textbox from dynamically generate text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had form that can be dynamic generate when click add button. I want to get the total of all subtotal textbox(man_day_rates * estimated_man_days). But my current code only calculate the first input row. How can I auto calculate all the subtotal input.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var i=1;
     $('#add').click(function(){

             //$("#step-2").height(5000);
           if(i == 1){
                   //add_remove_button
                    $('#dynamic_field .add_remove_button').append('<button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn_remove">X</button>');
           }

          i++;


          //Add field document History



          $('.dynamic_field .rowTotal').before('<tr id="row1'+i+'"><td></td>\
         </td>\
         <td style="">\
               <input id="man_day_rates'+i+'" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="number" min="1" name="man_days_rate[]" >\
         </td>\
         <td style="">\
               <input id="estimated_man_days'+i+'" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="number" min="1" name="estimated_man_days[]">\
         </td>\
          <td style=""> <input id="result'+i+'" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12 sum" disabled type="text" name="" value=""/></td>\
          <td style="height: 20px;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn_remove">X</button></td>\
          </tr> ');


        //function to calculate sub total for dynamic input/input after the first input
            var man_day_rates = $('#man_day_rates'+i);
            var estimated_man_days = $('#estimated_man_days'+i);
            var result = $('#result'+i);

            estimated_man_days.keyup(function(){
                var total=isNaN(parseInt(estimated_man_days.val()* man_day_rates.val())) ? 0 :(man_day_rates.val()* estimated_man_days.val());
                result.val(total);
                //alert(total);

            });

            man_day_rates.keyup(function(){
                var total=isNaN(parseInt(estimated_man_days.val()* man_day_rates.val())) ? 0 :(man_day_rates.val()* estimated_man_days.val());
                result.val(total);
                //alert(total);

            });
     });
     
     
 //function to calculate subtotal
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".sum").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);

        }

    });

   $("#subtotal").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                                      <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table class="table  table-hover table-striped dynamic_field" id="dynamic_field" style="padding:0px;">
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr class="headings">
                                      <th class="column-title">#</th>
                                     ]
                                      <th class="column-title" style="min-width:110px;">Man Day Rates (RM)</th>
                                      <th class="column-title" style="min-width:110px;">Estimated Man Days </th>
                                      <th class="column-title"style="min-width:110px;">Subtotal (RM)</th>
                                      <th class="column-title"style=""></th>
                                      </th>

                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>

                                  <tbody>
                                          <tr id="row01" class="row01">

                                                   <td>1</td>
                                                  
                                                  <?php
                                                        $i = 1;

                                                  ?>
                                                  <td style="">
                                                        <input id="man_day_rates<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="number" min="1" name="man_days_rate[]" >
                                                  </td>


                                                  <td style="">
                                                        <input id="estimated_man_days<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="number" min="1" name="estimated_man_days[]" >
                                                  </td>


                                                   <td id=""> <input id="result<?php echo $i; ?>" type="text" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12 sum" disabled name="" value=""/></td>
                                                   <td class="add_remove_button" style="height: 20px;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;"></td>


                                          </tr>


                                          <tr id="" class="rowTotal" style="background-color:white;">

                                                  <td style="border:none;visibility: hidden;"></td>
                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>
                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>


                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>


                                                  <td style="border:none;text-align:right;padding-right:0px;" >
                                                          <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="name">Subtotal
                                                          </label>
                                                  </td>


                                                   <td style="border:none;" > <input id="subtotal" type="text" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" disabled name="subtotal" value=""/></td>
                                                   <td class="" style="border:none;height: 20px;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;"></td>


                                          </tr>

                                          <tr id="" class="" style="background-color:white;">

                                                  <td style="border:none; visibility: hidden;"></td>
                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>
                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>


                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>


                                                  <td style="border:none;text-align:right;padding-right:0px;" >
                                                          <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="name">6% GST
                                                          </label>
                                                  </td>


                                                   <td style="border:none;" > <input id="result" type="text" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" disabled name="" value=""/></td>
                                                   <td class="" style="border:none;height: 20px;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;"></td>


                                          </tr>

                                          <tr id="" class="" style="background-color:white;">

                                                  <td style="border:none; visibility: hidden;"></td>
                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>
                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>


                                                  <td style="border:none;">

                                                  </td>


                                                  <td style="border:none;text-align:right;padding-right:0px;" >
                                                          <label class="control-label col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" for="name">Total
                                                          </label>
                                                  </td>


                                                   <td style="border:none;" > <input id="result" type="text" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12 sum" disabled name="" value=""/></td>
                                                   <td class="" style="border:none;height: 20px;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;"></td>


                                          </tr>



                                  </tbody>
                                </table>


                        </div>


                        <div><button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary "><span class="fa fa-plus" style="margin-right:5px;"></span>Add Items</button></div>
```

I had form that can be dynamic generate when click add button. I want to get the total of all subtotal textbox(man_day_rates * estimated_man_days). But my current code only calculate the first input row. How can I auto calculate all the subtotal input.

Comment: I can't find a call to `calculateSum` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Here i am not going to write code, just give you a suggestion, because i already develop this kind of stuff.

you need to create blur event on **Man Day Rates** And **Estimate Man Days** to multiply and store to subtotal. because subtotal field is disable, you no need to create any event on this. add class subtotal to all subtotal field.

now inside blur event you need to loop by this

```
var total = 0;

$(".subtotal").each(function()
{
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
});

$("#grand-subtotal").val(total);
```

you should use on event if your fields on generated by javascript code.